# ACF Relationship Posts how to show additional content

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a relationship between my custom posts Work and Talent using Advanced Custom Fields.

I am currently showing posts from Talent on my work pages with the following posts:

```
<?php 

                    $artist = get_field('artist');

                    ?>
                    <?php if( $artist ): ?>
                        <ul>
                        <?php foreach( $artist as $artist ): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $artist->ID ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo get_the_title( $artist->ID ); ?>
                                </a>


                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

However I would like to be able to show/pull-through a field that is in my artist sections on my work pages. I have tried doing the below but it doesnt work:

```
<?php 

                    $artist = get_field('artist');

                    ?>
                    <?php if( $artist ): ?>
                        <ul>
                        <?php foreach( $artist as $artist ): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $artist->ID ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo get_the_title( $artist->ID ); ?>
                                </a>


                                <?php the_field( 'artist_summary' ); ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding artist ID as the second parameter in the_field(), like so:

```
<?php the_field('artist_summary', $artist->ID); ?>
```

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/the_field/